# Android sidebar

Tags: android, sidebar, firefox-sidebar

I've been using firefox for Android and really like the use of the sidebar to hold shortcut icons and the like.  How would I go about creating a similar bar myself with the following attributes:

1. progressively revealed as I swipe in one direction
2. progressively hides as I swipe in the other direction
3. can be a custom width
4. I can dynamically inject layout in to it or it can hold static content

Is there any open source code available?  If not, what approach would I use to create this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you're describing a [Gallery control](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html). There are some examples in the ApiDemos project [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Gallery1.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this isn't what I was looking for.  I want the sidebar to be vertical, along the side of the screen and only shows when the user swipes left or right across the screen.

Comment: I think this control can be made with a heavily customised Gallery control.  Would be interested to see if anyone else has developed anything like this

Answer (score 0):

The first part can be solved by using a ListView. The second part I don't know yet. I'm looking for such a component as well.